# Max connections on a port

Tags: java, apache, server, operating-system

I am trying to implement a web socket server in `java`. The code for the server is :-

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(9000);
LOGGER.info("Listening on port :: 9000");
serverSocket.bind(socketAddress,5 );
while (true) {
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    Processor processor = Processor.getInstance(processorCounter++);
    try {
        processor.begin(socket);
    } catch (AppException e) {
        LOGGER.info(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

I am creating a new thread `Processor` which accepts the `socket` and begins to publish `response` on it without closing the connection. The connection is long-term and persistent.

When I hit this server with around 2000 `requests`, I observe that no more than `249 threads` are getting created. The question is that why no more than `249 threads/processors` are being spawned?

PS.: 
`requests` are being sent from Google Chrome
`Javascript` that makes the request -

```
const func1=function(){
    for(var i=1;i<=2000;i++){
        var ws=new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000");
ws.onopen=function(event){
    ws.send("are you a teapot?! from client "+i);
};
ws.onmessage=function(event){
console.log("Server says : "+event.data);
};
ws.onerror=function(event){
console.log("error () -> "+JSON.stringify(event));
};
ws.onclose=function(event){
console.log("close () -> "+JSON.stringify(event));
};}
}
```

Comment: Are you getting connection refused error?

Comment: How fast are you making requests?

Comment: @mwarren I have added the `JS`script which initiates the request.

Comment: @Conscript error is `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9000/' failed: net::ERR_FAILED`

Comment: cant make much out if it. :/

Comment: what SO are you using?

Comment: @josejuan SO means?

Comment: Operating System

Comment: @Conscript it is windows 10

Comment: Windows has limited the number of network connections https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d33de0fe-ba31-459a-8a43-201875c9ebe0/max-concurrent-connection-limit-on-windows-10-license-servers?forum=win10itpronetworking

Comment: @Conscript That would be OS. Not SO.

Comment: @josejuan There is nothing in your link except baseless speculation.

Comment: @josejuan the limit is just 20. I am able to feed `250 connections` concurrently

Comment: @OP Try increasing the backlog from 5 to say 50.

Comment: @user207421 can you help me out here?

Comment: @user207421 no difference

Comment: Well, you're being pretty optimistic trying to create 2000 WebSocket connections from a single client. What's the purpose here?

Comment: Try 
new ServerSocket(port, 50);

Comment: @user207421 I infer from your remark that it is generally not optimal. I assure you that this is for knowledge purpose.

Comment: @Conscript just did, no difference

Comment: Okay, how are you monitoring the number of threads

Comment: Every thread upon spinning gets Logged with the processorCounter  in a file @Conscript

Comment: sample log `2019-07-17 16:34:05 [Processor - 244] INFO  handler.Processor  - Processor - 244`

Comment: any errors on the server side?

Comment: yeah, `java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
 at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
 at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
 at handler.Processor.run(Processor.java:54)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)`

Comment: @Conscript this happened on some of the threads

Comment: Sounds to me like the server just can't start a processor thread fast enough and the accept is missing some requests.

Comment: Ok, this clearly shows that some of the threads that you keep count are closed, and you're not taking this into account.

Comment: @mwarren does accept() miss request? is it a known bug?

Comment: @Conscript not possible on server side as I am not closing the socket. are you hinting that workers might be getting closed on client? If you want to try on your local setup I can share the code

Comment: You are not closing the socket, but I think the threads that are handling the requests are constantly being created and destroyed.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12876277/3404777

Comment: No thats not the case. I think it is being blocked by the client.